# How to enable <Ctrl+Backspace> with Tmux, Neovim and Alacritty to delete the previous word?

Tags: terminal, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, alacritty

I use the alacritty terminal, and neovim editor with tmux.

At first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (for deleting a previous) wasn't working at all in the terminal. So added the following line to `alacritty.yml`:

```yml
key_bindings:
  - { key: Back, mods: Control, chars: "\x17" }
```

And this enabled the keybinding in alacritty. And now it deletes a word in the terminal. So I added the following in my neovim keybindings:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("i", "^H", "<C-W>", { desc = "Delete previous word", noremap = true, silent = true })
```

And this enabled it in neovim. But when I open vim in **tmux**, it doesn't work. I tried adding the following

- `bind-key -n C-BSpace send-keys C-BSpace`
- `bind-key -n C-BSpace send-keys ^H`
- `bind-key -n ^H send-keys ^H`
- `bind-key -n ^H send-keys C-BSpace`

Nothing seems to work. I looked up on the web for any other answers, but I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

So before I set the option in alacritty when I do run `$ cat` (or first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> it shows me `^H`, but after adding that keybinding in alacritty, it doesn't do that anymore, it directly starts deleting a word before it. But neovim doesn't do the job.

Also I tried `$ cat` on two different terminals (xfce4-terminal and terminator) and both gave me `^H`. I don't know how to set the keybinding in these terminals. Just presssing on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in these terminals just acts like a single <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it does the same thing on tmux as well (when used on those terminals).

**EDIT [SOLVED]**:
I had a binding set for Ctrl-W in my tmux config. As one of the comments suggested:

> Why do that when Ctrl-w already deletes the previous word both in insert mode in neovim and in the command line?

And my answer was because I already have a binding set to Ctrl-W, so I tried removing that keybinding, and it works. My configs:

`alacritty.yml`:

```yml
key_bindings:
  - { key: Back, mods: Control, chars: "\x17" }
```

`nvim/init.lua`:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("i", "^H", "<C-W>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

These two combinations actually fixed it. But when vim converted Ctrl-Backspace to Ctrl-W, and because I had Ctrl-W set as a binding in my tmux config, I think tmux was maybe interfering with that specific binding. I am not sure. But this is how I fixed it.

Comment: "now it deletes a word in the terminal" -- it is _never_ the terminal that decides whether to delete a word. It's the individual application, such as your shell (bash, zsh, ...) or vim or whatever app you're running, or for simple tools like `cat` it's the kernel's cooked mode tty code according to the stty settings. But never the terminal. So it doesn't make sense to talk about whether it works or not in your terminal without telling what app is running inside.

Comment: "xfce4-terminal and terminator [...] Just presssing on Ctrl+Backspace in these terminals just acts like a single Backspace" -- I don't think this is true. Most terminals, including these ones (I've verified terminator right now) send `^?` on Backspace and `^H` on Ctrl+Backspace. Use the tool `showkey -a` to verify.

Comment: I never noticed, or probably never cared about Ctrl+Backspace not working at `cat` and friends. I assume people rarely type into such apps where basic line editing (e.g. left-right arrows) isn't available. Having to hold Backspace a bit longer because Ctrl+Backspace doesn't work to delete a word is miniscule problem compared to the lack of left-right cursor movement. I wouldn't change the standard `^H` to `^W` and thus leave known territory. I would leave the terminal's default `^H` for Ctrl-Backspace and adjust the rest of the apps (except the kernel's cooked mode).

Comment: @egmont Thanks. But I solved it. It was not working because of a keybinding I set for `Ctrl+W` in tmux config